# Giving the same file as argument gives different output in c++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, argv, nand2tetris

I am doing the project 6 of nand2tetris course, which is to create an assembler. In my assembler called myassembler.cpp, if I give a file called MaxL.asm in two different ways, the output is very different. 
Here, if I do the following :

```
ebin@tux:~/ass3/assignment3$ ./myassembler  MaxL.asm >test.txt
ebin@tux:~/ass3/assignment3$ cat test.txt
0000000000000000
1111110000010000
0000000000000001
1111010011010000
0000000000001010
1110001100000001
0000000000000001
1111110000010000
0000000000001100
1110101010000111
0000000000000000
1111110000010000
0000000000000010
1110001100001000
0000000000001110
1110101010000111
```

The output is correct, and this is what I want. However if I do the following,

```
ebin@tux:~/ass3/assignment3$ ./myassembler < MaxL.asm >test.txt
ebin@tux:~/ass3/assignment3$ cat test.txt
1110001100000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
1110110000000000
111000000
1110101010000000
111000000
1110101010000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
111111000
111000000
1110101010000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
1110101010000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110110000000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
111000000
111000000
1110001100000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
1110001100000000
111000000
111000000
111000000
1110111010000000
1110001100000000
1110101010000000
111000000
1110111111000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
1110111111000000
1110101010000000
1110101010000000
```

The output is wrong. For submission of this, it has to work in the second way. I do not understand what is wrong when I put **<** before the file name.

Here is the code snippet that reads the file

```
ifstream fin(argv[argc-1]);
fin.open(argv[argc-1]);
```

What is wrong in the way I take input ? How to fix it? TIY

Comment: @sam My crystal ball shows that people are definitely going to hold you to that "only today" promise, and you will be sorry.

Comment: I can't wait for tomorrow then ! The whole community is going to do my job for me yey. I will go play video games

Comment: that was very helpful. It was very exciting to fix my own bug, and yea  I have succeeded on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` is the input redirection character, and is handled by the shell and not your program.

If you check your arguments in the second invocation, you will notice that you don't have any arguments.

That means when you use `argv[argc - 1]` you are using `argv[0]` which is the executable program.

You must check if `argc` is larger than `1` before using the `argv` array.

If `argc` is equal to `1` then you should read from `std::cin` instead. This is very easy if you put all your actual code in a separate function, and pass the stream (by reference) to it. Perhaps something like

```
void function_that_does_actual_work(std::istream& in)
{
    // Do lots of useful and important stuff...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
        function_that_does_actual_work(file);
    }
    else if (argc == 1)
    {
        function_that_does_actual_work(std::cin);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No file provided\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: And he do not havt to open the file twice. Giving the filename to the constructor does open the file already. He do not need to call `open` after this.

Comment: I understood what have gone wrong. Thanks to you. Didnt use your format, but able to fix the problem. Thank you very much